# Why does Ubuntu Java server disconnect clients?

Tags: networking, server, java

I am using Ubuntu Linux 12.04.1 LTS Edition. I hosted a Java server and it worked fine till yesterday, when a sudden disconnection of 500 clients occured.

I got an error `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` after connecting to the server.

Why am I getting this error? Is there any IP filter is activated in Ubuntu after the sudden disconnection ?

Comment: What kind of server is a "java server"? How are those clients connected (in a local network or remotely) ?

Comment: Do you mean a node.js server?